# Can a 32bit application access a 64bit sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

As the title states really, I need to know if a 32bit application can access a 64bit sql server database?

Comment: No, all computers in the world have to switch form 32 to 64 bits at the same time.  The 64-bit era will begin in a glorious bing bang!

Comment: @Andomar That actually sounds more like IPv6.

Comment: @vcsjones: that actually sound more like sarcasm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes

An application won't care if the target database server is 32 or 64 bit, Windows/Unix, Server/Mainframe, local or in the cloud. All it knows is the connection string it sends to a driver on the local OS.

To be clear, the local OS and driver don't care about 32 or 64 bit on the target system

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can and usually there is no problem.

Some large datasets might cause an issue but you would need a record with over 3gb of data...

Comment: Can you explain the "large datasets" thing please?

Comment: 32 bit systems can only address up to 4,096 MB. If you have a database result of that size, you will not be able to load it. Probably not going to happen, but the limitation is there.

Comment: I've never tried loading a 4GB resultset on *any* system. Just wanted to clarify what you meant...

Comment: Yup. Someone could load a large binary (like a series of dvd images) as binary blobs. Insane, but nothing would prevent that.

Comment: -1 Even a 32 bit client is able to download large BLOB (>4GB) via streaming from the server. And even a 32 bit server is able to serve large BLOB (>4GB) content. You can retrieve the content by chunk, depending of the database abilities of course, so there is no such 4 GB limitation here. With most database drivers, not all resultset is to be loaded at once in memory: rows are retrieved one by one, and BLOB can even be retrieved by chunk, using streaming. It will be probably slow, but most serious 32 bit databases are told to handle that.

Comment: Sure there are techniques to handle that kind of scenario, but most ORM are not ready to handle it.